# GoogleDeveloper console "Google Map Android API V2" option is not viewed to enable

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, android-mapview, android-maps-v2

In Google Map developer console try to enabling the API v2 of google maps but it is not viewed in options, i've shared my screenshot as below, because of not enabling v2 the mapview is not displayed in my android application, please help me to fix on this.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you created credentials to access your enabled API. If not means please refer below link, 
https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158857?hl=en_US

Comment: Did you got any ERROR log? when you trying to load the map ?